# LARAVEL register function executed twice

Tags: laravel

I have a function for user registration in my app. The first execution of the function was successful, but it runs again the second time. I can't seem to find the error. What might be causing this issue? Also the sweet alert does not show up even after returning an error of a duplicate email address.

here is my route:

```
Route::post('/register-user',[RegisterController::class, 'registerUser'])->name('register-user');
```

here is my ajax code(i am using ajax and not form submit):

```
 // ADD STUDENT RECORD
 $("#btn-register").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var first_name = $('#reg_first_name').val();
    var middle_name = $('#reg_middle_name').val();
    var last_name = $('#reg_last_name').val();
    var birthdate = $('#birth_date').val();
    var email = $('#reg_email').val();
    var emailConfirm = $('#reg_email_confirm').val();
    var data = {
        'first_name': $('#reg_first_name').val(),
        'id_number': $('#reg_id_number').val(),
        'middle_name': $('#reg_middle_name').val(),
        'last_name': $('#reg_last_name').val(),
        'birthdate': $('#birth_date').val(),
        'email': $('#reg_email').val(),
    }


    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Sending email',
        html: '<lord-icon src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/gzmgulpl.json" colors="outline:#242424,primary:#1663c7,secondary:#f1bc31" style="width:150px;height:150px"></lord-icon><br>Please wait while we send your email.',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowEnterKey: false,
    });



    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var errcount=0;

    //FIRST NAME VALIDATION
    if(first_name == ""){
        console.log('Please add a First Name');
        $('#reg_first_name').addClass('is-invalid')
        errcount++
    } 
    $("#reg_first_name").keypress(function(){
    $("#reg_first_name").removeClass('is-invalid');
    });
    $("#reg_first_name").mousedown(function(){
    $("#reg_first_name").removeClass('is-invalid');    
    }); 

    //the rest of the validations...

    if(errcount>0)
        return;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/register-user",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { 
            if (response.status == 422 && response.responseJSON.error.email) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'That email is already in use. Please try another one.',
                    });
            } else {
                $('#reg_first_name').val('');
                $('#reg_middle_name').val('');
                $('#reg_last_name').val('');
                $('#reg_email').val('');
                $('#birth_date').val('');
                $('#reg_email_confirm').val('');
                $('#reg_id_number').val('');
                $( "#checkbox-signup" ).prop( "checked", false );
                $( "#btn-register" ).prop( 'disabled', true );

                var mp4Element = $('<video>')
                .attr('src', '../assets/images/confettimp4.mp4')
                .attr('style', 'width:150px;height:150px')
                .prop('autoplay', true)
                .prop('loop', true);

                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Almost There!',
                    html: mp4Element.prop('outerHTML') + '<br>Please check your email before proceeding to the Login Page',
                    icon: 'success'
                });
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

this is the controller code for user registration:

```
public function registerUser(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $initialValue = [
        'step1' => TRUE,
        'step2' => FALSE,
        'step3' => FALSE,
        'step4' => FALSE,
        'step5' => FALSE,
        'step6' => FALSE,
        'step7' => FALSE,
        'step8' => FALSE,
        'step9' => FALSE,
        'step10' => FALSE,
        'step11' => FALSE,
        'step12' => FALSE,
    ];
    
    $requestData = $request->validated();

    DB::beginTransaction();
    
    try {
        $user = UserModel::create(array_merge($requestData, $initialValue));

        $user->application_code = "DRM-2023-" . str_pad($user->seq_id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $user->manual_message = '<html>';
        $user->account_status = 1;
        $user->save();

        DB::commit();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::abort();
    }
    
    // Send activation email to user
    $data = [
        'title' => 'Welcome to DRM',
        'body' => 'Thank you for registering with us',
        'activation_code' => $user->application_code,
        'first_name' => $user->first_name
    ];
    
    try {
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new MailNotify($data));
    } catch (Swift_TransportException $e) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Sorry! Please try again later'], 500);
    }

    // Return success response
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'You have registered successfuly',
        'first_name' => $user->first_name,
        'middle_name'=> $user->middle_name,
        'last-name'=> $user->last_name,
        'birthdate' =>$user->birthdate,
        'email'=> $user->email,

    ]);
}
```

this is the code from RegisterRequest:

```
class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
  /**
   * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, mixed>
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'middle_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'birthdate' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:sample_table',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'email.unique' => 'The email address is already in use. Please use a different one.',
    ];
}
```

}

snippet of the function being called twice:

[image]

Comment: maybe you have a multiple click issue? create a function to check if register was clicked or not.

Comment: quick question, does `DB::abort()` exists in laravel? were you looking for `DB:: rollBack `?

Comment: maybe `unbind()` will help you. [docs](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: thanks ill keep that in mind and try those suggestions